# Как с помощью js прописать стили в css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Есть способ применить стили `inline` через внутренний объект `style` у `DOM` элементов. Возможно иным способом применить стили по мимо замены класса, что бы эти свойства можно прописать в css или что - то в этом роде.

Comment: Не очень понятно, что требуется. В Вашем вопросе 2 способа уже есть: замена класса и замена стилей через style...  Наверное, Вы имеете в виду, что нужно что-то типа этого: `element.setAttribute('class', 'имя_класса_для_css');`

Comment: $("#id_element").css({"color":"red"});

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов, вы понимаете за что отвечает объект style у DOM элементов и вообще знаете что такое css? возможно ли поменять свойства в css не inline, а через css или может есть иной способ.

Comment: @Даниил, цитирую себя: `Есть способ применить стили inline...`. ваш пример делает это `inline`. Аналогично можно сделать через: `document.getElementById('id_element').style.color = "red";`

Comment: `npm install aphrodite`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var styleNode;
function addStyle() {
  styleNode = document.createElement("style");
  styleNode.innerText = ".test{background-color:lightgreen;}";
  document.body.appendChild(styleNode);
}
function removeStyle() {
  styleNode.parentNode.removeChild(styleNode);
}
```

```css
div {
height:100px;
background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<button onclick="addStyle()">Add Style</button>
<button onclick="removeStyle()">Remove Style</button>
```

Comment: подскажите где я могу прочитать про метод `append`? Я просто плохо знаю какую роль играет функцию [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element). Пробовал создать объект на ее основе, но не работает как конструктор, хотя находиться в цепочки прототипом как объект.

Comment: я так понял что этот метод создает в `html` тег `style` и туда пишет стили. Возможно ли отредактировать сам `style.css` который был загружен?

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный Я не понимаю, чего Вы хотите достичь. Попробуйте сформулировать. Отредактировать внешний css файл нельзя. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Comment: спасибо, я разобрался. сейчас перечитал ваш ответ и все понял.